# jQUery Code doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Here is my jQuery code. It shows some prompt messages if the user doesn't fill in all fields.

```
$('#register').click(function(){
    var sign_up_button = $(this).val();

    var pass = $('#password').val();
    var retype_pass = $('#retype_password').val();

    if (pass != retype_pass)
    {
        return false;
    } else if ($('#firstname').val() == '' || $('#lastname').val() == '' || $('#mobile_number').val() == '' || $('#email_address').val() == '' || $('#password').val() == '' || $('#retype_password').val() == '') {
        $('#danger_container_all_fields').attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
        $('#message_fill_up_all_fields').html("Please, Fill up all fields!");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

I also saw this JS code online for placeholder in IE, but there's some conflict in it that suppresses the message of my jQuery code.

```
var _debug = false;
var _placeholderSupport = function() {
    var t = document.createElement("input");
    t.type = "text";
    return (typeof t.placeholder !== "undefined");
}();

window.onload = function() {
    var arrInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var arrTextareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
    var combinedArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++)
        combinedArray.push(arrInputs[i]);
    for (var i = 0; i < arrTextareas.length; i++)
        combinedArray.push(arrTextareas[i]);
    for (var i = 0; i < combinedArray.length; i++) {
        var curInput = combinedArray[i];
        if (!curInput.type || curInput.type == "" || curInput.type == "text" || curInput.type == "textarea")
            HandlePlaceholder(curInput);
        else if (curInput.type == "password")
            ReplaceWithText(curInput);
    }

    if (!_placeholderSupport) {
        for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
            var oForm = document.forms[i];
            if (oForm.attachEvent) {
                oForm.attachEvent("onsubmit", function() {
                    PlaceholderFormSubmit(oForm);
                });
            }
            else if (oForm.addEventListener)
                oForm.addEventListener("submit", function() {
                    PlaceholderFormSubmit(oForm);
                }, false);
        }
    }
};

function PlaceholderFormSubmit(oForm) {    
    for (var i = 0; i < oForm.elements.length; i++) {
        var curElement = oForm.elements[i];
        HandlePlaceholderItemSubmit(curElement);
    }
}

function HandlePlaceholderItemSubmit(element) {
    if (element.name) {
        var curPlaceholder = element.getAttribute("placeholder");
        if (curPlaceholder && curPlaceholder.length > 0 && element.value === curPlaceholder) {
            element.value = "";
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                element.value = curPlaceholder;
            }, 100);
        }
    }
}

function ReplaceWithText(oPasswordTextbox) {
    if (_placeholderSupport)
        return;
    var oTextbox = document.createElement("input");
    oTextbox.type = "text";
    oTextbox.id = oPasswordTextbox.id;
    oTextbox.name = oPasswordTextbox.name;
    //oTextbox.style = oPasswordTextbox.style;
    oTextbox.className = oPasswordTextbox.className;
    for (var i = 0; i < oPasswordTextbox.attributes.length; i++) {
        var curName = oPasswordTextbox.attributes.item(i).nodeName;
        var curValue = oPasswordTextbox.attributes.item(i).nodeValue;
        if (curName !== "type" && curName !== "name") {
            oTextbox.setAttribute(curName, curValue);
        }
    }
    oTextbox.originalTextbox = oPasswordTextbox;
    oPasswordTextbox.parentNode.replaceChild(oTextbox, oPasswordTextbox);
    HandlePlaceholder(oTextbox);
    if (!_placeholderSupport) {
        oPasswordTextbox.onblur = function() {
            if (this.dummyTextbox && this.value.length === 0) {
                this.parentNode.replaceChild(this.dummyTextbox, this);
            }
        };
    }
}

function HandlePlaceholder(oTextbox) {
    if (!_placeholderSupport) {
        var curPlaceholder = oTextbox.getAttribute("placeholder");
        if (curPlaceholder && curPlaceholder.length > 0) {
            Debug("Placeholder found for input box '" + oTextbox.name + "': " + curPlaceholder);
            oTextbox.value = curPlaceholder;
            oTextbox.setAttribute("old_color", oTextbox.style.color);
            oTextbox.style.color = "#c0c0c0";
            oTextbox.onfocus = function() {
                var _this = this;
                if (this.originalTextbox) {
                    _this = this.originalTextbox;
                    _this.dummyTextbox = this;
                    this.parentNode.replaceChild(this.originalTextbox, this);
                    _this.focus();
                }
                Debug("input box '" + _this.name + "' focus");
                _this.style.color = _this.getAttribute("old_color");
                if (_this.value === curPlaceholder)
                    _this.value = "";
            };
            oTextbox.onblur = function() {
                var _this = this;
                Debug("input box '" + _this.name + "' blur");
                if (_this.value === "") {
                    _this.style.color = "#c0c0c0";
                    _this.value = curPlaceholder;
                }
            };
        }
        else {
            Debug("input box '" + oTextbox.name + "' does not have placeholder attribute");
        }
    }
    else {
        Debug("browser has native support for placeholder");
    }
}

function Debug(msg) {
    if (typeof _debug !== "undefined" && _debug) {
        var oConsole = document.getElementById("Console");
        if (!oConsole) {
            oConsole = document.createElement("div");
            oConsole.id = "Console";
            document.body.appendChild(oConsole);
        }
        oConsole.innerHTML += msg + "<br />";
    }
}
```

Can someone help me locate the conflict code. By the way, this code only conflict in IE. In other browsers it works really well.

Comment: Is the code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @Barmar yes it is inside the $(document).ready() it works good in other browsers except IE...

Comment: What debugging have you done so far? Are there any messages in the Javascript console? Have you tried setting breakpoints in your jQuery code to see if it's running? Can you make a Stack Snippet or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Is `#register` the submit button of your form? Your placeholder code has `oForm.attachEvent("onsubmit", function() {`, which replaces your submit handler with its own code.

Comment: @Barmar no error messages... when I omit the placeholder js code my JQUERY code above works just fine... but when I put the placeholder code it doesn't show the fill up all fields message... I think there is a conflict code there..

Comment: @Barmar in other browser it works just fine..

Comment: That's because only IE has `attachEvent`. In other browsers it falls through to the `addEventListener` code, which allows multiple handlers.

Comment: @Barmar yes you are correct sir... the #register is the id of my button... so what is the solution for that?.. I also have a guess that it conflict in the onsubmit but I don't know how to fix since i'm not that good in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this code:

```
if (oForm.attachEvent) {
    oForm.attachEvent("onsubmit", function() {
        PlaceholderFormSubmit(oForm);
    });
}
```

is replacing the jQuery submit handler. It only happens in IE because `attachEvent` is a non-standard, IE-only method. You have several options to work around this:

1. Just get rid of the above code. Then this part of the placeholder code won't work in old versions of IE (recent versions have `addEventListener`).
2. Change the order of the `if` and `else if` blocks in the placeholder code, so it tests for `addEventListener` first. That way, the override will only happen in old versions of IE. In general, it's best to test for new features first, and only fall back on old methods when they don't exist.
3. Run the jQuery code *after* the placeholder code. This way, it will add its submit handler to the submit handler that was added by the placeholder.